# Неактивное окно

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, c++

Как сделать так, чтобы окно при щелчке мышкой не получало фокус?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы окно было всегда неактивным, нужно добавить стиль [`WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543(v=VS.85).aspx), например, с помощью [`ModifyStyleEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1y6fbte.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Просто в процедуре обработки окном сообщений, устанавливаешь обработчик для `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` и `WM_LBUTTONUР`, `WM_RBUTTONUР`. по идее должно сработать.